# Contrast statement in proc surveyreg

Tags: sas

I estimate the following model:

```
proc surveyreg data = data;
cluster id;
model y = x1 x2 x3 x4;
run;
quit;
```

I want to test the following two hypotheses jointly: x1 = x3, x2 = x4.

I know how to do it in other regression procedures. For example, in proc panel I just do: "test x1 = x3, x2 = x4;" and it gives me the respective Wald Test statistic. However, I have trouble doing it (via use of the contrast statement?) in proc surveyreg.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the documentation for the CONTRAST statement.

```
proc contents data=sashelp.fish varnum;
proc print data=sashelp.fish;
   run;
proc glm /*surveyreg*/ data=sashelp.fish;
   model width = Weight Length1 Length2 Length3 Height;
   contrast 'length1=length2, length3=height' length1 1 length2 -1, length3 1 height -1 / e;
   run;
proc reg data=sashelp.fish plots=none;
   model width = Weight Length1 Length2 Length3 Height;
   TEST1: Test length1=length2, length3=height;
   run; quit;
```

[image]

[image]